# How to import external library py7zr into AWS Glue Job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, 7zip

I am working with AWS Glue. A 7z file must be extracted from S3 and subsequently transformed and loaded the lines of a resulting .txt into an RDS database. I need to use the py7zr library to be able to extract the file.

I already imported py7zr as external in the Glue Job configuration in my CloudFormation template. However, it forces me to import the other libraries it depends on, and I'm mainly having problems with the pybcj library, but I have the following error:

[pybcj error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXorB.png)

This is how I have configured the parameters of my glue job, I also have the --extra-py-files where I declare the s3 repositories of py7zr and and other of its dependencies:

[Default Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw49C.png)

--additional-python-modules seems to have no effect.
Could you tell me how I can import py7zr and all its dependencies successfully? Thanks.

Comment: Glue runs a pip install on any dependent libraries that are passed as parameters in the `--additional-python-modules` and then proceeds to the `--extra-py-files` param . Download the third party library and upload it to s3. Pass the s3 path as the value to the `--additional-python-modules` param and things should work.